# Why is this form not sending g-recaptcha-response?

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha

I'm trying to set up recaptcha on a site. I've done this before and I'm not seeing why this wouldn't work.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="emailProcess.php">
               <label for="fullName">First and Last Name</label>
                <br/>
               <input id="fullName" type="text" name="fullName" required>
                 <br/><br/>
               <label for="email">Email</label>
                <br/>
               <input id="email" type="text" name="email" required>
                 <br/><br/>
                 <label for="eventDate">Event Date</label>
                <br/>
               <input id="eventDate" type="text" name="eventDate">
        </div>

        <div class="contactRight">
               <label for="eventTime">Event Time</label>
                <br/>
               <input id="eventTime" type="text" name="eventTime">
                 <br/><br/>
               <label for="eventLocation" style="margin-top:5px;">Event Location</label>
                <br/>
               <input id="eventLocation" type="text" name="eventLocation">
                 <br/><br/>
               <label for="servicesRequested" style="margin-top:5px;">Service(s) Requested</label>
                <br/>
               <input id="servicesRequested" type="text" name="servicesRequested">
               <br/><br/>
        </div>

        <label for="howHear" style="margin-top:20px">How did you hear about us?</label>
        <textarea class="howHear" id="howHear" name="howHear" rows="4" cols="59"></textarea>
        <br/>
         <label for="comment" style="margin-top:20px">Extra Comments</label>
        <textarea class="comment" id="comment" name="comment" rows="4" cols="59"></textarea>
        <br/><br/>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey-is-here"></div>
        <br/>
        <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Send Message">
        <button class="resetButton" type="reset" value="Reset Form">Reset Form</button>
        </form>
```

I have this included in the head tag of the page: `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`

On the page this info is being sent to when I try to echo out `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];` the page is completely blank.

Comment: @miken32 Content can appear on the page. For example if I were to do `echo $_POST['comment']` it would show up.

Comment: I guess the obvious question then becomes, is this script inserting anything into your form? Use your web inspector to check that.